# Keep text inside CSS shape without using blank divs

Tags: css, shapes

[This article](http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/) shows several shapes that can be created in CSS. The square the the rectangle easily support adding text inside the shape.  The oval and circle cuts the text out. The triangle doesn't show any text.  The heart shows the text behind it.  And because text was added the diamond doesn't appear to be a diamond anymore.

Is there any decent way for one to go about adding text to these CSS Shapes?  Is there something easier than using floating divs to position the text in a separate element onto of the CSS Shape element?

Example of some results: http://jsfiddle.net/EVBYt/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- CSS shapes,
- text in a *safe zone* in a CSS shape and
- text in CSS shapes where text will fill available space as much as possible

are three very different beasts!

The shapes you refer to are made with one constraint: a single element is used. This leads in some cases to 0x0 px elements with background-color entirely applied onto pseudo-elements. Obviously your text won't display properly in these cases and you'll have to redo entirely these shapes with other methods.

**[CSS regions](http://html.adobe.com/webstandards/cssregions/)** has been proposed by Adobe to W3C. Just wait a few years for standardisation and implementation :)

During this long wait, Tantek Celik and Eric Meyer who played with blank divs ~10 years ago (example: http://meyerweb.com/eric/css/edge/curvelicious/demo.html ) are still relevant.
Provided you want to achieve designs that will explode when *larger text* is selected by users in IE8 or with a single level of zoom text in Firefox. Though with fluid sizing in `em` maybe?

I'd use **SVG** if I was forced to style text into such complicated shapes.

Comment: Thanks for that info. I knew there had to be at least talk about CSS regions, sad to here its not now.  I don't want to use images so I think I will end up using floating divs above the CSS shapes. (This question related to this project: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12650965/css-diamond-shape-centric-website-issues)

Comment: CSS Regions is now supported in [the latest] Safari, however, it looks like I still can't use that to do what I want to accomplish. It seems I would still be limited to rectangular shapes. Am I missing something?

Comment: Sounds like what you want is CSS Shapes, not Regions. CSS Shapes are supported today in Chrome, Safari and Opera - http://sarasoueidan.com/blog/css-shapes/

Comment: @RazvanCaliman Thanks. [First Working Draft of CSS Shapes](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/WD-css-shapes-1-20130620/) was published 9 months after this question and answer so it'd need some update yes